# Property of limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $f,g,h: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, have linear growth or slower, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} h(x)-f(x)g(x)=d$ for some finite $d$, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=c$ for some finite $c$. Is it possible to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} h(x)-cg(x)=d$. I am most interested in showing this in the case when $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} h(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} g(x)=\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true. Consider e.g. $h(x) = x^{1/2}$, $f(x) = x^{-1/2}$, and $g(x) = x$.

Then certainly
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} h(x) - f(x) g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{1/2} - x^{1/2} = 0 = d, $$
and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0 = c$, but
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} h(x) - c g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{1/2} = \infty \neq d. $$